# Cross domain tracking of goals

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to use cross-domain tracking to track a goal across 2 seperate sites on 2 different domains?

I have 2 different domains with unique opt-in forms and need to be able to track a goal if a user signs up on either site 1 or site 2.

Both sites link to each other through the nav.

A user will reach site 1 through a PPC ad but if they don't convert on site 1 but instead convert on site 2, I would still like to associate that conversion with the same campaign.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking - if you already have set up cross domain tracking this will work without any more ado.  If you need general advice on cross domain tracking you should first follow the documentation and then get back with specific problems you encounter.

Comment: Thanks, tried using the allowlink method but the campaign source/medium and further UTM parameters are not being passed to the second domain. Any ideas on how to pass the UTM parameters to the second domain?